# Elasticsearch - How to get popular words list of documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a temporary index with documents that I need to moderate. I want to group these documents by the words they contain.

For example, I have these documents:

1 - "aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff"

2 - "bbb mmm aaa fff xxx"

3 - "hhh aaa fff"

So, I want to get the most popular words, ideally with counts: "aaa" - 3, "fff" - 3, "bbb" - 2, etc.

Is this possible with elasticsearch?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Doing a simple term aggregation search will meet your needs:

(where `mydata` is the name of your field)

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/test/data/_search?search_type=count&pretty' -d '{
  "query": {
    "match_all" : {}
  },
  "aggs" : {
      "mydata_agg" : {
    "terms": {"field" : "mydata"}
    }
  }
}'
```

will return:

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "mydata_agg" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key" : "aaa",
        "doc_count" : 3
      }, {
        "key" : "fff",
        "doc_count" : 3
      }, {
        "key" : "bbb",
        "doc_count" : 2
      }, {
        "key" : "ccc",
        "doc_count" : 1
      }, {
        "key" : "ddd",
        "doc_count" : 1
      }, {
        "key" : "eee",
        "doc_count" : 1
      }, {
        "key" : "hhh",
        "doc_count" : 1
      }, {
        "key" : "mmm",
        "doc_count" : 1
      }, {
        "key" : "xxx",
        "doc_count" : 1
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a solution i searched for. Didn't test query you provide, but get the point what i have to do.

Comment: I am surprised it doesn't revolve around the `_mtermvectors` API

Answer (score 11):

It might be because this question and the accepted answer are some years old, but now there is a better way.

The accepted answer does not take into account the fact that the most common words are usually uninteresting, e.g. stopwords such as "the", "a", "in", "for" and so on.

This is usually the case for fields that contain data of type `text` and not `keyword`.

This is why ElasticSearch actually has an aggregation specifically for this purpose called [Significant Text Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-bucket-significanttext-aggregation.html).
From the docs:

- It is specifically designed for use on type `text` fields
- It does not require field data or doc-values
- It re-analyzes text content on-the-fly meaning it can also filter duplicate sections of noisy text that otherwise tend to skew statistics.

It can, however, take longer than other kinds of queries, so it is suggested to use this after filtering the data with a query.match, or with a previous aggregation of type [sampler](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-bucket-sampler-aggregation.html).

So, in your case you would send a query like this (leaving out the filtering/sampling):

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "keywords": {
            "significant_text": {
                "field": "myfield"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This may be a perfect solution for many use cases, but keep in mind, it's not the same thing as a terms aggregation with a stopwords filter.
`The significant words are the ones that have undergone a significant change in popularity measured between a foreground and background set.`
This means you can end up with words in the list that are considered _significant_ but aren't necessarily the most _common_, even when stopwords are taken into consideration. They're simply more common in the foreground set than the background.